Puppeteer request interception: how to know if current HTTPRequest is due to an iframe's document loaded
Could anyone tell me how I could know the following?
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', (req) => {
   if (req.isInterceptResolutionHandled()) {
      return;
   }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   //HOW TO KNOW IF CURRENT "req" IS DUE TO AN "<iframe>"'s DOCUMENT LOADED?
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
});
await page.goto('https://web-site.com/web-page-containing-iframes');

I have tried without success executing the following fragment (just replacing the comment):
let frame = page.frames().find(f => f.url() === req.url());
if (typeof frame !== 'undefined') {
   console.log('EUREKA!');
}

Obviously it doesn't work because the new URL hasn't been loaded into the iframe.

Why do you need to know this? There might be another way to achieve whatever your real goal is, if you don't mind providing context.

Hello, @ggorlen.
I need to do the following:
I detect that the request is the loading of an HTML document in an iframe.
I make the request (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/globals.html#fetch) and I get the resulting HTML.
I modify the HTML (by adding my custom "
OK, can you [edit] the post to show the page and describe your full use case? Why do you need an open door to make calls between the frames? I'm still not sure why you want to do this sort of thing out of the blue.
